# Handle different user types with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design

I'm starting a web app project with Spring framework + Hibernate. I want to model two different types of users in the application: **doctors** and **patients**. They have some common attributes like name, email, telephone number etc, but the doctors have more specific attributes like collegiate number, specialities, studies etc.

This is an E-R model (Hibernate approach) simplified without attributes.

[image]

As you can see, the relationships will become 1 to 1, but one of them will always be null. I've also though about using inheritance but I've never worked with it in Hibernate so I don't know which is the best approach and why. Which is the simplest and efficient way to go here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Inheritance` approach is just one way to share common attributes between two managed types in a persistence context.  Don't forget that `@MappedSuperclass` does precisely the same without coupling the two data types together in any hierarchical sense.

One thing to consider is whether a `Doctor` can be a `Patient` from a domain perspective, and if so, what implications does that open up from an API perspective?

Would it be acceptable to call `#getPatientDiagnosis(Patient patient)` and pass it a `Doctor`?  From a code perspective, it compiles and is logical because you elected inheritance, but from a domain perspective, that makes no sense.

This is one reason I often advocate for a separation in domain vs persistence models.  There is often design decisions that make perfect sense from a data model perspective at the data store, but those decisions introduce technical debt at higher abstractions.

If it were me reusing my entities as my domain models, I'd elect `@MappedSuperclass` unless you have another compelling reason to use inheritance in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Naros , I didn't know about the `@MappedSupperclass` annotation, but I think this is not what I need, because I'm working with a User Account which will be stored in the session for each user, so what I want is to retrieve with the User Account id a `Patient` or a `Doctor`, so I think this solution doesn't fit very well right?

Comment: Your diagram tells me that an `Account` is composed of two relatioships which are both optional, a `Doctor` and a `Patient`.  That aside, how you interpret reading the two attributes and branching is an application concern and doesn't necessarily dictate the requirement of inheritance at the persistence layer unless you feel you'd like to model the data that way in your tables.

Comment: Thanks @Naros , I understand. So, which approach is better: 1- Optional 1 to 1 relationships and check wether an `Account` has a not null `Patient` or `Doctor` or 2- Inheritance (with the corresponding db tables) and find a `Patient` or a `Doctor` by the `Account` identifier each time that I need it?

Comment: Frankly that's a subjective question because at some point, you'll likely have some code which needs to branch based on whether it is a `Doctor` or `Patient`.  With the explicit mapping, that becomes a null-check.  With inheritance, that becomes an instanceof-check.  I still defer back to my point my concerns about the API where you explicitly expect a `Patient` but using inheritance permits passing a `Doctor` in those instances.  If it were me, I would use explicit mappings and use if-checks.

Comment: Oh yes, that's true, you mentioned it before and I agree with your API concerns, so yes, I'm going to do it using explicit mappings. Thanks a lot for your point of view!